# Accessing webservices protected by SSO

Tags: java, web-services, single-sign-on

I wrote a simple java client using java.net.URLConnection to connect to a webservice protected by SSO. I also extended the java.net.Authenticator and provided my own authenticator with user name and password for the SSO but stll I am not able to access the webservice from my java client.

Is there somthing that I am missing. 
Can you please help me?

Thanks,
Lokesh

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out what login mechanism is used by the site.  If you've supplied an authenticator and that isn't working, the site is likely to be redirecting the client to a login page with a form for entering login credentials.  You should be able to figure out what request to send from the form HTML.

The other thing you might be missing is that you have to keep track of the cookies that the server is attempting to set, and supplying them in your requests.  The chances are that there will be a session token that allows the server to match your requests with your authenticated identity ... once you've logged in.